# HTML5 video frame by frame advance and rewind problem on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, html5-video

I have ran into a problem trying to do frame by frame advance with html5 video on the iPad.

I have a test page up here
http://playgr8sports.com/ipad/videotest.html

With the back and forward buttons using the html 5 video tag.

This works great exactly how it should do **in Chrome**. It jumps through at 0.03 sec per click.

But when I try it on the iPad, it jumps random chucks of seconds and is no longer frame by frame.

All I can find is that it has something to do with the iPad not handling "currentTime" in javascript very well.

I cannot find any work around. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug with the current 4.2 SDK.  I have 4.3 Beta installed on my iPad and it works great on here.  There are a few issues I've seen thus far with the 4.2 browser that are fixed in 4.3

Also add this to your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

will help limit the zooming in and out deal when clicking on the links and not quite hitting them.

I'll check for any work arounds, but seeing as it's a version issue, might not be any..